# How to receive Django post_save signal on AJAX query?

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-signals

I use AJAX request to create an order, also I have a `post_save` signal that should be executed after the order will save. Whether is it possible to receive this `post_save` signal on an AJAX request?.. because I don't get aything, the signal handler is ignored =|

Comment: If you have a post-save signal, it is always sent on save. It has nothing to do with whether the original request is Ajax or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Okay. After I have read whole [documentation of signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/) in depth I didn't find anything that helped me to solve the prolem. Then I have read [this post](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) that describe the signals at great length. So, I forget to add the `default_app_config` in the `__init__.py` of my module:

```
default_app_config = 'cmdbox.profiles.apps.ProfilesConfig'
```

Hope this hint will help someone like me)

**2.** The answer for the main question, thanks to the [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman):

> If you have a post-save signal, it is always sent on save. It has
>   nothing to do with whether the original request is Ajax or not.